# Why is, for a group scheme of finite type, "smooth" (resp. irreducible) equivalent to "geometrically reduced" (resp. geometrically irreducible)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, schemes

I have some questions about two statements from Bosch's "Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra" about ***algebraic varieties*** (page 479). Since I still don't have the permission to add images I quote the relevant excerpt:

> ...The notion of properness has been introduced in 9.5/4. It means that the
>   structural morphism $p: A \to Spec(K)$ is of finite type, separated, and universally
>   closed. For the property of smoothness see 8.5/1. It follows from 8.5/15
>   in conjunction with 2.4/19 that all stalks $\mathcal{O}_{A,x}$ of a smooth $K$-group scheme $A$
>   are integral domains. Since abelian varieties are required to be irreducible, they
>   give rise to integral schemes. Also let us mention that *for $K$-group schemes of
>   finite type smooth is equivalent to geometrically reduced*, which means that all
>   stalks of the structure sheaf of $A×_K \bar{K}$ are reduced. In addition, let us point out
>   that *for $K$-group schemes of finite type the property irreducible can be checked
>   after base change with $\bar{K}/K$* so that we may replace irreducible by geometrically
>   irreducible...

We fix an abelian variety $A$ over field $K$. By definition an abelian variety over $K$ is a proper smooth $K$-group scheme that is irreducible.

Following two questions:

1. Why is for a $K$-group scheme of finite type ***smooth*** equivalent to ***geometrically reduced***?
2. Why under same conditions as in 1.  (so $K$-group scheme of finite type) the property ***irreducible*** is equivlaent to ***geometrically irreducible***?

Remark: Here I previously asked this question in MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136827/abelian-varieties

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the title of your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $G/K$ be a group scheme of finite type.

1. $G/K$ is smooth if and only if $\bar G / \bar K$ is smooth. Suppose $\bar G$ is reduced, then it has a smooth $\bar K$-point $x$ (because we are over an algebraically closed field). But $\bar G(\bar K)$ acts transitively on itself, so now every closed point of $\bar G$ is smooth, so $\bar G$ is smooth. (And of course if $\bar G$ is smooth then it is reduced.)
2. The point is that $G$ comes with a section, the neutral element $e\in G(K)$. Suppose that $\bar G$ is reducible, then since $\bar G^{\rm red}$ is reduced and hence smooth, we see that $\bar G$ is disconnected. If $\bar G^\circ$ is the connected component of the neutral element $e$, then since the Galois group ${\rm Gal}(\bar K/K)$ acts on $\bar G$ preserving $e$, it has to preserve $\bar G^\circ$, and so $\bar G^\circ$ descends to give a component of $G$, so $G$ is disconnected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One penible question: When you talk about the ${\rm Gal}(\bar K/K)$-action on $\bar G = G \otimes \bar{K}$ do you implicitely mean the action on "points" $\bar{G}(\bar{K})= Hom(\bar{K}, \bar{G})$ via composing $\phi \mapsto \phi \circ g$ for a $g \in {\rm Gal}(\bar K/K)$ or the action via "base change" namely that $g$ induces automorphism on $\bar{G}$ via $id \otimes g$?

Comment: @Karl_Peter I think the latter action induces the former on $\bar K$-points. Here it is enough to say that the profinite group ${\rm Gal}(\bar K/K)$ acts continuously on the underlying topological space $|\bar G|$ of $\bar G$ (or just the subspace of closed points $\bar G(\bar K)$) and the quotient space is identified with $|G|$.

Comment: But what is concretely the "canonical" action of ${\rm Gal}(\bar K/K)$ on the underlying topological space $|\bar G|$?

Comment: The argument in the answer that the identity component of $G$ over the algebraic closure of $K$ is defined over $K$ applies only in characteristic zero. Otherwise the proof is more difficult.

Comment: @anon: do you know a recommendable reference where the case with positive characteristic is explained?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger: Sorry again for the annoying asking again but I'm not sure if I understood your argument correctly about how concretely the action on $|G|$ works. As you explained there is given a canonical action of ${\rm Gal}(\bar K/K)$ on $\bar{G}(\bar{K})$ by conjugating. According to your last comment that suffice. Do you mean this in the sense that this action on $\bar{G}(\bar{K})$ automatically extends/induces to an action on $|G|$? Since $\bar{G}(\bar{K})$ is dense in in $|G|$? Or did you mean that in another way?

Comment: @Karl_Peter See Section b of Chapter 1 of Milne: Algebraic Groups, The theory of group schemes of finite type over a field, Cambridge UP, 2017.

Comment: Just to comment to @Karl_Peter if $X/k$ is any finite type scheme and $X(k)\ne\varnothing$ then $X$ is connected if and only if it's geometrically connected (e.g. see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3168956/16497)